# Has the default password requirements in PHP ever changed, such that password_needs_rehash() would return true for default options?

Tags: php, password-hash, password-storage

I have recommended to a client that their login system implements `password_needs_rehash`, so that as their version of PHP is upgraded, the user accounts within their web app will have the password automatically rehashed and re-saved. My reason for doing so is to ensure that as brute-forcing passwords becomes more capable, with CPUs emerging of increasing speed, password hashes need to be upgraded.

I start from the assessment that the PHP hashing facilities were introduced in PHP 5.5 and we've had five major versions since then, with 7.4 around the corner. Have any of these changed the default hashing algo or the internal cost option, such that presenting an "old" hash would return true if the rehash test function is used?

If they have, I could grab an old copy of PHP, generate a hash, and then use that in my API tests, to show that an old hash is indeed upgraded in the later version of PHP.

It [looks like](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) 7.2 and 7.3 included new hashing algos, but the default was not changed, and on that basis, this method would return false. I have not found any information about whether the default cost has been changed since these functions were added.

If it is the case that the default `password_hash` settings have never been changed that would cause a rehash, I could add a manual `cost` parameter based on the timing script on the `password_hash` doc page, but that requires manual intervention that my non-technical client is unlikely to undertake themselves. Can it be automatic based on PHP upgrades?

Comment: As of now, https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/password.c#L605, it's really just based on costs/thread/memory (if overriden via app settings). But there also just hasn't been a hashing method that warranted deprecation. (Which is the unmentioned purpose of _needs_rehash)

Comment: Ah, thanks @mario - perhaps for this piece I will use the timing script to find out what cost to use, and then add that to manual config. That will be enough to trigger a needs-rehash in the login process.